# function to convert to gmt date in java script

Tags: javascript, date, date-conversion

i had a departureDate = date string(16-Apr-2012), time String(05:00), and **TimeZone(Asia/Dubai)** 
and arraivalDate = date string(16-Apr-2012), time String(02:00),and **TimeZone(America/New_York)**

now i need to compare the above dates
ie.,

```
if (departureDate > arraivalDate) {
    // do something
}
```

Purpose of this comparision is to check arraival time is before departure time..
is there any function in javascript to do this? 
Please provide the whole function..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) documentation.

There is the [`getTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) method that allows you to get a numeric value corresponding to the time for the specified date according to universal time. Which means that the value returned by the `getTime` method is the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

Which means you can do the following:

```
if (departureDate.getTime() > arrivalDate.getTime()) {
    // Do something
}
```

Provided you declared your dates the following way:

```
var departureDate = new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, day, hour, minute, second))
    arrivalDate = new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, day, hour, minute, second))
```

So that it respects the timezones. You need to specify UTC dates though. Javascript has no built-in way to handle timezones better than this. As my first sentence states it, look at the documentation about the Date object.

Edit: After talking with you in the chat, here is what I think you want:

According that you have the following:

```
var orgti = document.getElementById('orginTimeZone').value; 
var desct = document.getElementById('descTimeZone').value;
var selfwDepDate = document.forms[0].fwDepartureDate.value; 
var selfwDepTime = document.forms[0].fwDepartureTime.value; 
var selfwArrDate = document.forms[0].fwArrivalDate.value; 
var selfwArrTime = document.forms[0].fwArrivalTime.value;
```

You can do this to compare both dates:

```
var departureDate = new Date( Date.UTC( selfwDepDate + selfwDepTime ) ) // This creates a date with what you got
var arrivalDate = new Date( Date.UTC( selfwArrDate + selfwArrTime ) ) // This too

// Now the tricky part: you substract the timezone, so that you get the same referential for both dates
departureDate = departureDate.getTime() - ( orgit * 3600000 ) // Multiplying by 3600000 to transform hours into milliseconds since "getTime" returns milliseconds
arrivalDate = arrivalDate.getTime() - ( desct * 3600000 ) // Same

// Now, you've got two timestamps based on dates with the same referential. You can use:
if ( departureDate > arrivalDate ) {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: but time zone of two dates are diferent.... thats the issue..and am actually having three arguments.. one is date, time and timezone..

Comment: The timezone is taken into account, since `getTime` returns the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 UTC. If you specify the timezone in your `Date` object, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: can u provide me the full function to do comparision.. as i said i had three different arguments in hand,, date, time and timezone seperately..

Comment: or else can u tell me how to parse date with these three arguments.>?

Comment: but we are specifying the time zone rite?

Comment: Mr. Florian u surely made my answer down just google w3c and you will know what I mean try - www.w3.org/ also w3c = World Wide Web Consortium (W3C). So just beat out brother; you are in wrong side bro.. no personal issues here. -1 for that ;)

Comment: It is UTC. You have to translate your dates to UTC before creating the Date object.

Comment: by the way forgot to add -1 just literally for u.. dont take actions on things you dont know

Comment: hey, i make it clear.. i had a String date, String time and string time zone.. in my case timezone will change based on the location.. so tell me how this will opt on it?

Comment: HI.. THIS WAS REALLY A GREAT ANSWER BUT...'var departureDate = new Date( Date.UTC( selfwDepDate + selfwDepTime ) ) 
  var arrivalDate = new Date( Date.UTC( selfwArrDate + selfwArrTime ) ) ' `var departureDate = new Date( Date.UTC( selfwDepDate + '120' ) ) 
  var arrivalDate = new Date( Date.UTC( selfwArrDate + '200' ) )` FOR ABOVE TWO I GOT VALUE AS **NAN**

Answer (score 1):

Just as stated already, you'll still need to use getTime to extract actual seconds to compare. If you have numerical offsets you can simply add them to your dates before comparison.

```
// Assuming departure is in +4 TZ (Asia/Duabai) and arrival is in -4 TZ (America/New_York)
var departureMsec = departureDate.getTime() + (+4 * 3600 * 1000)
var arrivalMsec = arrivalDate.getTime() + (-4 * 3600 * 1000)
if (departureMsec > arrivalMsec) {
    // Do something
}
```

Things get more complicated if you don't have offsets as numbers or time zones in your input are not limited to some common subset. I'm not aware if there is a tzdata version with handling code for JavaScript, so I'll give you pointers how to do it by hand. If you work with limited amount of zones and none of them have daylight savings, then you can simply put offsets in hash:

```
var offsets={
    "Asia/Dubai": +4,
    "America/New_York": -4,
}
```

And use data from there. If you need arbitrary amount of zones, your best bet would be parsing tzdata to such a hash and implementing manual handling of correct daylight adjustments for every possible date, which gets harder and harder with each year, because with change of laws you'll have to support old conversions for old dates and new for new dates. I can add more details if you explain more about your needs.